# Bundler couldn't not resolve host when trying to fetch Gem from a Github repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, rubygems, bundle

It's expected that running `bundle install` fetches the gems from GitHub repositories that have their GitHub url specified in the Gemfile.

In my case, I get a bunch of errors:

```
bitkoin-api git:(main) bundle install    
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/......
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.comUsers/bashorun/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/cache/bundler/git/double_entry-822076161735bb2415359ce4bc5bd8848ea609b9/': Could not resolve host: github.comUsers

Retrying `git clone --no-checkout --quiet /Users/bashorun/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/cache/bundler/git/double_entry-822076161735bb2415359ce4bc5bd8848ea609b9 /Users/bashorun/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bundler/gems/double_entry-
6427f6bcaeec` at /Users/bashorun/dev/bitkoin-api due to error (2/4): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone --no-checkout --quiet /Users/bashorun/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/cache/bundler/git/double_entry-822076161735bb2415359ce4bc5bd8848ea609b9 /Users/bashorun/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bundler/gems/double_entry-6427f6bcaeec` in directory /Users/bashorun/dev/bitkoin-api has failed.

If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory '/Users/bashorun/dev/bitkoin-api'

Retrying `git clone --no-checkout --quiet /Users/bashorun/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/cache/bundler/git/double_entry-822076161735bb2415359ce4bc5bd8848ea609b9 /Users/bashorun/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bundler/gems/double_entry-6427f6bcaeec` at /Users/bashorun/dev/bitkoin-api due to error (3/4): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone --no-checkout --quiet /Users/bashorun/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/cache/bundler/git/double_entry-822076161735bb2415359ce4bc5bd8848ea609b9 /Users/bashorun/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bundler/gems/double_entry-6427f6bcaeec` in directory /Users/bashorun/dev/bitkoin-api has failed.

If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory '/Users/bashorun/dev/bitkoin-api'

Retrying `git clone --no-checkout --quiet /Users/bashorun/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/cache/bundler/git/double_entry-822076161735bb2415359ce4bc5bd8848ea609b9 /Users/bashorun/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bundler/gems/double_entry-6427f6bcaeec` at /Users/bashorun/dev/bitkoin-api due to error (4/4): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone --no-checkout --quiet /Users/bashorun/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/cache/bundler/git/double_entry-822076161735bb2415359ce4bc5bd8848ea609b9 /Users/bashorun/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bundler/gems/double_entry-6427f6bcaeec` in directory /Users/bashorun/dev/bitkoin-api has failed.

If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory '/Users/bashorun/dev/bitkoin-api'

Git error: command `git clone --no-checkout --quiet
/Users/bashorun/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/cache/bundler/git/double_entry-822076161735bb2415359ce4bc5bd8848ea609b9
/Users/bashorun/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bundler/gems/double_entry-6427f6bcaeec` in directory /Users/bashorun/dev/bitkoin-api has failed.

If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory '/Users/bashorun/dev/bitkoin-api'
```

From the error, it looks like bundle tries to fetch the repository from an invalid url there by throwing `fatal: unable to access 'https://github.comUsers/bashorun/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/.../double_entry-822076161735bb2415359ce4bc5bd8848ea609b9/': Could not resolve host: github.comUsers`, `Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError`,  error.

NB: bundle install works well when all gems with Github urls are removed.

Gemfile:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '~> 2.7.2'

# Ruby on Rails
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.3', '>= 6.0.3.1'
gem 'bootsnap', require: false

# ActiveRecord
gem 'enumerize'
gem 'pg'
gem 'migration_data'
gem 'validate_url'
gem 'double_entry', git: 'https://github.com/buycoinsafrica/double_entry.git', branch: 'master'

# Firebase
gem 'google-cloud-firestore'

# Analytics
gem 'analytics-ruby'

# Crypto
gem 'coinbase', '4.2.2'
gem 'adequate_crypto_address'

# Orchestration
gem 'envied'
gem 'puma'
gem 'rack-attack', '~> 6.2', '>= 6.2.2'
gem 'redis', '~> 4.2', '>= 4.2.1'
gem 'redis-objects', '~> 1.5'

# CORS
gem 'rack-cors'

# PubSub
gem 'google-cloud-pubsub'

# ProtoBuf
gem 'protos-gem', git: 'https://access_token_redacted@github.com/buycoinsafrica/protos-gem', branch: 'master' # do not fear, access token has read only powers

# GraphQL
gem 'graphiql-rails', '~> 1.4'
gem 'graphql', git: 'https://github.com/buycoinsafrica/graphql-ruby', branch: 'master'

# GraphQL
gem 'artemis'
gem 'grpc'

# Webhook
gem 'convoy.rb'

# Authentication
gem 'devise'
gem 'knock', git: 'https://github.com/nsarno/knock.git', branch: 'master'

# 2fa
gem 'active_model_otp'
gem 'rotp', '~>3.3.1'

# Background jobs
gem 'clockwork'
gem 'sidekiq', '~> 6.0', '>= 6.0.7'
gem 'sidekiq-failures'

# Business logic
gem 'interactor-rails'

# Console love
gem 'awesome_print'

# Paystack Integration
gem 'paystack', git: 'https://github.com/timigod/paystack-ruby.git', branch: 'feature/ta-transfers-verify'

# Synapse Integration
gem 'synapse_pay_rest'

# HTTP Requests
gem 'httparty'

# Notifications
gem 'hertz'
gem 'hertz-email'
gem 'hertz-twilio'
gem 'sinch_sms'

# Optimisation
gem 'bullet'
gem 'goldiloader'
gem 'pghero'
gem 'pg_query', '~> 1.2'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'

gem 'by_star'
gem 'twitter'
gem 'time_difference'
gem 'humanize'

# Error logging
gem 'sentry-raven'

gem 'browser'

# Soft delete
gem 'discard', '~> 1.1'

# Track changes
gem 'audited', '~> 4.8'

# Push notifications
gem 'fcm', '~> 0.0.6'

# Param validation
gem 'rails_param', '~> 0.11.0'

# Serializers
gem 'fast_jsonapi', '~> 1.5'

# Telegram
gem 'telegram-bot'
gem 'telegram-bot-types'

# Drip
gem 'drip-ruby', require: 'drip'

# Websocket Client
gem 'faye-websocket', '~> 0.10.9'

# Device detection
gem 'device_detector'

gem 'active_record_query_trace'

# View emails in development
gem 'letter_opener'
gem 'letter_opener_web'

# Phone number formatting
gem "phonelib"

# Social feed
gem 'stream-ruby', '4.4'

# Heroku Orchestration
gem 'platform-api', '~> 3.0.0'

group :development, :test do
  # Factories
  gem "factory_bot_rails"
  gem 'faker'

  # Debugging
  gem 'pry-rails'

  # Testing
  gem 'rspec-rails'

  # Orchestration
  gem 'dotenv-rails'

  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'timecop'
  gem 'recursive-open-struct'
end

group :development do
  # Annotate models
  gem 'annotate'

  # Code quality
  gem 'rubocop'
  gem 'rubocop-rspec'
  gem 'rubocop-faker'

  # Preloading
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # gem 'spring'
  # gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'

  # ERD
  gem 'rails-erd'
end

group :test do
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: %i[mingw mswin x64_mingw]
  gem 'wdm', platforms: %i[mingw mswin x64_mingw]
  gem 'webmock'
  gem 'fakeredis'
  gem 'simplecov', require: false

  # CircleCI
  gem 'rspec_junit_formatter'
end
```